# Cambiar color del texto del evento segun el estado en que esta el paciente FullCalendar PHP

Tags: php, fullcalendar

estoy queriendo cambiar el color del texto del evento segun el estado en que se encuentra el paciente.
Pude cambiar el color del punto, solamente con el evento "color" con el siguiente codigo

```
color:'<?php if ($turno->getEstado() ==1 ){
           echo "yellow" ?>
       <?php }else if ($turno->getEstado()==2){
           echo "red"?>
       <?php  }else if ($turno->getEstado()==3){
           echo "green"?>
        <?php } ?>',
```

Lo cual me muestra asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero cambiar el color del nombre del paciente (evento),  que muestre en que estado esta el paciente sus colores, lo probe con textColor pero no me esta funcionando, al igual que backgroundColor

Comment: yo lo resolvi con javascript... no con php

Comment: todo depende de como has hecho esa implementacion

Comment: Como lo tendria que hacer?

Comment: asumo que cada pasiente es un evento... bueno se supone que fullcalendar acept un json con los eventos... a cada evento le cascas el color: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventColor